# Segmentation fault when returning char*

Tags: c, pointers

Why does this program result in a Segmentation Fault when the line `return str + i - j;` is encountered ? I thought I was understanding the pointer concept pretty well but I clearly miss something here and I can't figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* ft_strstr(char* str, char* to_find) 
{
    int i;
    int j;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        j = 0;
        while (str[i] == to_find[j] && str[i] != '\0' && to_find[j] != '\0')
        {
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        if (to_find[j] == '\0')
            return str + i - j;
        else
            i = i - j;
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}

int main()
{
    char a[] = "fffo";
    char b[] = "ffo";
    char* f = ft_strstr(a,b);
    if (f)
        printf("%s\n", f);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Don't you have a `return 0` there? That looks fishy...

Comment: In GCC compiler, your program working fine..

Comment: @cuvidk: I can't test it right now, but your current code looks good. You could debug it and see what the values of `i` and `j` are and how they change.

Answer (score 4):

If your intent here is to find a string in another string, you should simply look into the standard `strstr` function since that is exactly what it is meant for.

If, however, your intent is to learn how to debug your code, your best bet is to sit down with a piece of paper thus:

```
  i        j      str               to_find
-----    -----    --------------    ------------
                  0  1  2  3  4     0  1  2  3  <- indexes
  ?        ?      f  f  f  o  \0    f  f  o  \0
```

and run that code through your head, line by line, updating changing variables as you go.

Nothing will make things clearer than single-stepping through your code manually.

Comment: I know there is a function which already does that. That's why the prototype of this function is so similar to that one. I just need to write something similar and that's it. Second, `return (0)` is not called on this example. The encountered return statement is `return str + i - j;`. Check with prints and you'll see.

Comment: And about the `return (0);`, it's place there intentionally, since the `strstr` function from `<string.h>` is returning a `NULL` pointer if the sequence was not found.

Comment: @cuvidk, I'm merely stating that since you blindly `printf` the return value, which is going to end badly if the string isn't found, hence why I stated your *calling* code should take that into account. I'll try make that clearer. It isn't, on its own, a problem with the function. To ascertain the problem with the function, you need debugging skills, which I am attempting to impart :-)

Comment: I changed it :D

Comment: totally unrelated to what I thought ... it's working pretty good, but I actually had 2 files (main.c and ft_strstr.c). When I was compiling, no linker error was being raised even if the prototype of `ft_strstr` was not declared in main.c .. I think I should close this issue or what should I do ?

Comment: And, now, I've changed my answer to suit :-) FWIW, that works both on my gcc and in my head so you may want to ensure you've posted/are-compiling the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine. It's unrelated to pointers after all, my bad, sorry. The problem was that I actually had 2 separate files (main.cpp and ft_strstr.c). Even if the prototype of `ft_strstr()` was not declared in main.cpp file, when compiling using `gcc main.cpp ft_strstr.c` the linker didn't raise any errors and it seems like when I was running the compiled executable it was resulting in a Segmentation fault. The strange thing though is that the function was executing (I know that since I tried to make some prints from `ft_strstr()`).